# Removing underline from <img> or <i> if wrapped by anchor link using :has()

Tags: html, css

```
<a href="link">
    <i class="icon is-ac-coloured fab fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i>
</a>
```

```
a:has(> img), a:has(> i) {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Why can I still see the underline on the image?

[image]

I'd like it to be removed if an anchor link wraps an image or an italic tag.

Comment: When you inspect element, do you see some other styles overwriting it? Is it even applied? Have you tried adding this style to `:visited` too? Oh, and `:has` is so experimental that no browser supports it yet

Comment: @Justinas :has actually works in many other classes I've been using so far. Anyway: https://imgur.com/a/R2iYaNM

Comment: :has isn't supported it's only in draft so you'll need some other selector

Comment: Again... I've used it already, and it works properly.

Comment: and again, `:has` will not work with all the browsers ...  https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has

Comment: It could sounds really silly I know, but I had a similar issue in the past.
Do you have a space or line break between the 2 elements? 
N.B. I meant space or line break not as a html tag but like a input by keyboard

Comment: if you can, please share the second part of your code

Comment: You guys were right, :has() wasn't actually working, there was just a difference in HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

:has() is a CSS4 selector its a working draft: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational, looking at https://caniuse.com/#search=%3Ahas there isnt great browser support. So that might be the reason you are seeing nothing its simply not being parsed.

Going to have to write this using JavaScript or alternatively attach a class to your anchors that are warping images and icons.

```
.remove-text-decoration {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: I think this looks like the only solution so far.